# What would be best approach to write JQuery Code in asp.net for Inser,Edit and Delete operation?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, performance, optimization

I have three button INSERT,EDIT and DELETE on sample.aspx page in .net application.I am doing some client side operation on every button click event using JQuery.What would be the best approach to write JQuery code as a performance point of view.

1.)Should i write separate click event for each button click as given below

```
$("#btnInsert").click(function(){
    //Insertcode
});
$("#btnEdit").click(function(){
    //Edit code
});
$("#btnDelete").click(function(){
    //Delete code
});
```

2.) Should i write a common function as given below

```
$("#btnInsert").click(function(){
    Operation("I")
});
$("#btnEdit").click(function(){
    Operation("E")
});
$("#btnDelete").click(function(){
    Operation("D")
});
function Operation(opType)
{
    if( opType = "I")
    {
        //Insert
    }
    if( opType = "E")
    {
        //Edit
    }
    if( opType = "D")
    {
        //Delete
    }
}
```

3.)Should i use OnClientClick event of every button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnInsert" runat="server" Text="INSERT" OnClientClick="return Operation("I");" />
<asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="EDIT" OnClientClick="return Operation("E");" />
<asp:Button ID="btndelete" runat="server" Text="DELETE" OnClientClick="return Operation("D");" />
```

OR

Is there any other optimization technique?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like in your first choice:

```
$("btnInsert").click(function(){
    //Insertcode
});
$("btnEdit").click(function(){
    //Edit code
});
$("btnDelete").click(function(){
    //Delete code
});
```

Option 2 seems bloated to me. And Option 3 defeats the point of jQuery!